# tooltip bootstrap is not loaded when I add a new component via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add new   lines and enable the tooltip, however when I run this function the bootstrap tooltip does not appear, leaving it default

I tried using the following command but it did not work

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function() {
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('#btn').click(function(){
     
     var newbutton = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip"> Hello <a>'
     
     $('#Content').append(newbutton);
     
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip">
Hello
<a>

<a id="btn" class="btn btn-default" > Create tooltip </a>

<div id="Content">

</div>
```

Comment: It isn't pretty but you can do instead: ``$e = $(newbutton).tooltip(); $('#Content').append($e);``

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would be a better option to use the jQuery appendTo instead of append. appendTo allows you to apply tooltip to the object you are adding and not on the container you are adding it to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('#btn').click(function(){
     
     var newbutton = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip"> Hello <a>'
     
     $(newbutton).appendTo('#Content').tooltip();
     
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip">
Hello
<a>

<a id="btn" class="btn btn-default" > Create tooltip </a>

<div id="Content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize new tooltips by re-running `$.fn.tooltip()`:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Already initialized elements are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Flewtje's answer is better and he was faster!

You can also add listeners to elements lower in the DOM hierarchy, such as to the container element, and utilise the [DOMNodeInserted](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Content').on('DOMNodeInserted', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function(evt) {
      $(evt.target).tooltip();
  });

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('#btn').click(function(){
     
     var newbutton = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip"> Hello <a>'
     
     $('#Content').append(newbutton);
     
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello Tooltip">
Hello
<a>

<a id="btn" class="btn btn-default" > Create tooltip </a>

<div id="Content">

</div>
```